# Why sin(0.2*x + pi) is aperiodic function?

Tags: signal-processing, wave

I know this might be too easy to be a question... but I can't get why sin(0.2*x + pi) is aperiodic?..

I tried to plot this in matlab and that's what I got:

[image: Matlab sin wave]

That should be periodic right? Instead in "Schaum's Outline of Digital Signal Processing" book it says it's aperiodic

[image: Solution of Schaum's Outline book]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **function** `f(x) = sin(pi + 0.2*x)` is periodic.

The **sequence** `sin(pi + 0.2*n)` where `n=0, 1, ...` is not periodic.

Comment: it should be _discrete_ if I understand this correctly.

Comment: That's true it's discrete. Now i get it :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sin(0.2*x + pi), x in R (i.e. x - real)` **is periodic**, as we could find such x0 that `sin(0.2*x + pi) = sin(0.2*(x + x0) + pi)`

`sin(0.2*x + pi), x in N_0 (i.e. x - natural and zero)` **is not periodic**. You've provided exactly the proof of that fact in page screenshot.